# Can my landlord live in a property I rent if I move out before the lease ends?

Tags: united-states, rent, deposits, landlord, tenant

We moved out two months earlier than our lease ends, but are still fully prepared to keep paying rent until May. We were responsible for getting the lawn mowed, so I had my dad go mow it. While he was there, he saw my landlord living there; is that legal?

Can my landlord still make us pay for the rent even though he’s living there before our lease ends? He also hasn’t said any more to us about whether or not we get our deposit back.

Comment: Where is the rent house located?

Comment: The Rental property is located in South Florida

Comment: This is more of a legal question than a financial one. Maybe try https://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can you show us the relevant part of your lease? When I rented, if I terminated the lease early, I was only liable for rent until they found a new tenant.

Comment: Our lease has not been terminated he just told us to try and find a tenant to take over the lease for us and then we wouldn’t have to pay the last two months rent but I could not find anyone and I told him this. So technically we still have a lease with that property until may 31st. I don’t know how to post photos on here. It’s my first time using the site.

Comment: @Kylie - sorry this happened - note that you don't "technically" have a lease - you surely DO HAVE a lease !!!!!  the guy is an a-hole and I'm sorry this happened

Comment: Did you dad definitely see *the landlord* living there, or did he see *someone* living there? How can you be sure he was living there, and not temporarily at the property for some other reason? What has the landlord said about this?

Comment: @Kylie to cut to the chase, pick up the phone and call the cops there, and report this nonsense. Then it will al be on record.  And don't EVER pay this idiot another cent.

Comment: @yoozer8 it would be a bigger issue if someone other than the landlord were living there. OP still has a lease. What if they came back to find another tenant there? Whose habitation rights/lease terms would trump the others? The landlord probably has some right to co-habitate at their own leisure depending on the local law and OP's lease terms, but I doubt there's any jurisdiction that lets a landlord straight-up double -book tenants *and charge them both* in the same living space so long as one person happens to be on vacation.

Comment: Anyway, this is clearly a legal question, not a money question. I'm not sure why it's still open here.

Comment: Leases often have a clause that says "this unit is for the exclusive use of <list of people on the lease and their minor children>". That cuts both ways - you can't house extra people in the unit, and neither can the landlord. Please check your lease.

Comment: Leases sometimes require you to live at the property (or specifically to not leave it uninhabited for more than a few nights), so you may be violating the terms by moving out. And the landlord is allowed to attend to maintain the property (subject to any notification requirements in the lease, but such requirements may be overridden in some circumstances). It is indeed a legal matter.

Answer (score 3):

To play devil's advocate: The landlord living in the house isn't actually costing you anything compared to having it sit empty. Your agreement with the landlord was that you would continue to pay rent unless *you* found someone to take over the lease, which you didn't. Now, since your lease is still valid, you have the right to use the property, but you explicitly told the landlord that you didn't plan to use it for the next two months. The landlord could argue he isn't denying you as long as he *would* vacate if you changed your mind and wanted to move back in.

Regarding the security deposit, did you have your inspection or at least take photos at the time you moved out? That is the main potential cost to you that I see, *if* the landlord tries to charge you for "damage" that wasn't there when you moved out. But it's only at the end of the lease that he owes you an accounting/return of the security deposit, so in that regard he hasn't wronged you yet.

You might be in a better position if you had terminated the lease early. This would likely trigger an obligation of the *landlord* to look for a replacement tenant. Depending on local law, you might no longer owe rent after some period even if no new tenant was found. Likely that would be longer than two months, so you would still owe the remainder of your lease if no one was found. You could argue that by living there himself, the landlord has found a new "tenant" (imputed rent). However, even this might not completely relieve you of the rent, if the house is intended for more than one person and so the value to him of living there alone(?) does not make up for the rent in the lease.

EDIT: It looks like Florida is [even more lenient](https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/tenants-right-break-rental-lease-florida.html) on the landlord in this situation than most states. The landlord is [allowed to "retake possession"](https://caretaker.com/learn/lease-breaks/lease-breaking-laws-in-florida) of an abandoned unit while looking for a new tenant. And if he didn't retake possession but left it empty, he wouldn't have to look for a new tenant at all but could simply continue to collect rent from OP.

So if the landlord can argue that the property is abandoned, he may be within his rights to live there *and* charge rent as long as he is looking for a new tenant.

Comment: Sorry guys, this is ............ nuts.   If a landlord, *or anyone* MOVES IN TO YOUR HOUSE, for goodness sake, call the cops immediately to get it all on record.  Then - if you can afford it - redial the phone to your lawyers.

Comment: terminated the lease early  - ?  unheard clause of in the US.

Comment: @Fattie Early termination ("breaking" a lease, typically with obligation on tenant to continue paying rent but obligation on landlord to mitigate damages by re-renting) is a [normal practice](https://www.allpropertymanagement.com/blog/post/what-landlords-should-do-when-tenant-wants-to-terminate-lease-early/) in the US.

Comment: @Fattie It is not just "anyone", it is the person who *owns* the house *and* has been notified that you no longer want to live there.

Comment: sure, you can **break** a lease - we're all done it when we were students or the like.  You need to edit your text "if you had terminated the lease early" to state "if you had broken the lease early.

Comment: I'm afraid your new "EDIT" para is just really wrong.  Nobody has *abandoned* anything.

Comment: @Fattie Regarding "abandoned", see the citation in Laconic Droid's comment on your answer.

Comment: I already explained why that is wrong, and it's not a citation.  Words have meaning, they did not "abandon" the contract.

Comment: @Fattie It's not your house. It's the landlord's house. They have the right to come and go as they please, and likely also have the right to co-habitate or even kick you out. And yes, moving to another state is arguably abandonment. Even if you pay rent, there's a 30 day period of no habitation going on where a landlord could say constitutes a reasonable belief of abandonment, given habitation in another state. Many apartment leases in the US stipulate you must spend a certain number or percentage of nights there per week/month to avoid abandonment clauses kicking in.

Comment: "They have the right to come and go as they please, and likely also have the right to co-habitate or even kick you out"  ????????

Comment: @TylerH !!! In which country do landlords have the right to come and go as they please? No, the landlord owns the house as a financial asset and a maintenance burden, but *you* are the one who lives there, and the law gives you the rights which are given to people who live there, such as the right to not let other people inside.

Comment: @user253751 The United States and I would expect most other nations with property rights, too. It's their property... they can be on it whenever they want, so long as they have an emergent reason to be there or so long as they give you notice. If you aren't living at the location, you won't be around to observe the notices, most likely.

Comment: @TylerH well, you are simply wrong. Being a tenant grants you rights which override the landlord's. The landlord's property rights include the right to not have tenants, but if he does have tenants, the tenants have rights too. Of course he can be "around" the location, anyone can, but he can't enter or do other things that strangers can't do

Comment: @TylerH yes, you say he needs an emergent reason or to have given notice. That means if he doesn't, then he doesn't have that right.

Comment: @user253751 Other reasons include, but are not limited to: abandonment, a clause included in the contract, etc. OP hasn't provided near enough information to ascertain anything beyond "the landlord was at the property". There are a myriad of things that could have precipitated the landlord being on the property legally.

Comment: Certainly in the UK a landlord can enter a property to inspect it or perform maintenance, but must give 24 hours notice (although it's not clear how notice would apply if you had moved out of state - could they e.g. put a letter through the property's door or leave a message on a landline phone even if you didn't see it?)

Comment: @StuartF Same in the US: my landlords always gave us 24 hours notice, even if they just wanted to grab some possession they were storing in the basement or attic.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, when a tenant moves out before the end of a lease, the landlord is obliged to make a reasonable effort to find a suitable replacement tenant. The original tenant is responsible for paying rent until the replacement tenant starts paying. If the landlord has moved in, I would consider that to be finding a suitable replacement tenant.

Answer (score -9):

1. I believe it is NOT LEGAL.  You're the tenant, you are not behind in rent, so only YOU have USE of the property.
2. I fear the best thing you can do is phone this idiot and say

> "Hi Steve.  Why are you living in the house? **We have already phoned the police because** we were so shocked to see some person in our rented house."

3. **Don't pay him a penny more rent.** Your only real leverage is withholding the rent.
4. If the person is such an asshole, it's very likely he will never return your deposit.
5. Can you call the cops? I would be inclined to do this:

Call simply the local police in that town and say

> "Hi guys. There's an unusual problem. We rent the home at *address* from *full name and address of asshole*. Currently we are actually out of town for two months, we are living in California. But. *full name of asshole* has moved in to the house!  Again we are the renters and of course we are fully paying the rent. Buy the owner has moved in to the house!  We are unsure if you can help us with this, what do you think?"

It may help.

You could hire a lawyer, but of course, that just means you'd get screwed due to the cost - the "little guy" always gets screwed in such situations.

You have no power other than not paying the rent.  And buy the way, screw the lawn, don't attend to it!

I hope that you still have enough rent to pay, that, if you don't pay it it makes up for the deposit this fool will steal from you.

Best of luck.

Comment: I think the police will not eject the landlord, even if the tenant shows a valid lease. After all, the landlord can show he *owns* the place and will have a story to justify what he's doing ("tenant moved out early, I need to keep the property safe from vandals/squatters..."). The police will not make the landlord return rent to the tenant (that's a court matter). Once it looks like a nontrivial civil dispute, the police will not act without a court order.

Comment: If the OP has vacated the property and returned the keys, I don't think it will be illegal for the landlord to move someone else into the apartment (including himself). What will be illegal is to charge the OP rent if a new tenant has been found, but the police aren't going to remedy that by removing the new tenant from the premises, nor can they force the landlord to return the OP's rent. I'm not sure what is the expected/desired outcome from calling the cops, aside from being a scare tactic or getting information on the courts.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie: The explanation given by the landlord will show up on the written police report.  He'll have to make up his mind whether the property is still rented to the original tenants, in which case the police will only allow him to act as a landlord (make repairs, but not reside there) or whether he admits that he's ended their lease to make room for a new occupant.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie - as I said, OP should *call* the cops.  "aside from being a scare tactic or getting information on the courts"  Well yes ..........  of course.  One might as well ask "why call the cops after a traffic accident."  Call the cops, **obviously and right now.**

Comment: Florida Bar's website states "If the tenant permanently moves out before the end of the rental term and leaves the property vacant, this usually is considered to be an abandonment of the tenant’s rights". Unlikely the cops will be of any use here except to confirm at this stage you're dealing with a civil matter. A lawyer will be more useful.

Comment: @LaconicDroid - I just don't buy it. At the other extreme, if I happen to go on a few-month holiday, that's not what the Florida Bar Website is discussing.  Phone calls are free - call the cops and then it is on record, AND the dirty landlord knows it's a serious issue.

Comment: It is really a bad idea to write hyperbolic answers urging people to take drastic actions with potential legal consequences just because you "don't buy it".

Comment: Hi everyone, Thankyou for all the input. I forgot to reply but for those wondering what happened we did end up calling him out on it and he indeed was living there with no intention of finding a new tenant. The conversation got a bit out of hand and he ended up blocking both me and my husband so we had no way to reach him. After about a week he unblocked my husband and said he was going to send our deposit back but then blamed us for the washing machine being broken we had told him months prior about it not working but he told us that if we wanted a new one we had to drive almost and hour away

Comment: to pick it up ourselves, no way we were doing that. After all was said And done he kept the deposit. We are just happy to be out of there and there was no legal action needed to be taken.

Comment: Even as a civil matter, you would have to show some financial loss or other damages from the landlord moving in.

Comment: Well, one can see the outcome just above, where the OP explains the outcome. As I predicted, **the OP completely lost**. To repeat yet again ... The OP should have called the cops to (maybe, with luck) add some heat. Of course in an ideal world, or if vast sums of money were at stake, the OP would lawyer-up, but that's not a solution here. As it says below, *"Sorry guys, this is ............ nuts. If a landlord, or anyone MOVES IN TO YOUR HOUSE, for goodness sake, call the cops immediately to get it all on record. Then - if you can afford it - redial the phone to your lawyers."*